# How to get CloudSolrClient object without using CloudSolrClient.Builder() method

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am getting the CloudSolrClient connection object using the below statement

```
CloudSolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHost).withHttpClient(getSolrHttpClient()).build();
```

But i can see CloudSolrClient.Builder() method is deprecated.

What is the alternative way to get the CloudSolrClient object using zookeeper host and withhttpclient authentication?

Comment: `withZkHost` is deprecated; you're expected to use `new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zkServers, Optional.of("/solr"))` now, where `zkServers` is a List of strings - for example `ArrayList`: https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/main/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrClient.java#L151

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the answer.Here what does Optional.of("/solr") mean.What does "/solr" represents.It is representing any thing?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the answer.CloudSolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zkList,Optional.of("/solr"));

I am getting error like  "Type mismatch: cannot convert from CloudSolrClient.Builder to CloudSolrClient".Can you please suggest.

Comment: You still have to end with `.build()` as previously (as shown in the linked source): `final SolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zkServers, Optional.empty()).build();`. The path represents the chroot / path that Solr uses inside ZK, so `Optional.of("/solr")` or `Optional.empty()` are the common configurations.